# How to compile c code in php - linux environment

Tags: php, gcc, fedora

I am using fedora 14 and gcc compiler to compile c code.
Using php(lampp) i am trying to call helloworld. I am trying the following code

```
exec('gcc hello.c', $x,$y);
echo $x; //line 4
echo "<br/>>>> "; 
echo $y;


 Notice: Array to string conversion in /opt/lampp/htdocs/learning/index.php on line 4
Array
>>> 1
```

Any idea how to compile and get the output. Plz help :)

I did the

```
 $compilecode=shell_exec("gcc -o hello hello.c 2>&1");
 Output:
 failed to create /var/cache/ccache/tmp (Permission denied) in echo.
```

What permission issue.

Comment: Just curious: why do you want to do this?

Comment: i am learning sir...so trying new things

Comment: show us var_dump($y);

Comment: var_dump($y) is int(1)

Comment: The notice is because you are trying to echo $x, which is an array. Show var_dump($x);

Comment: var_dump($x) - array(0) { }

Comment: any suggestion how to resolve this...i give 777 to htdocs

Comment: 777 on htdocs is not a good practice, and at the same time, it is not the problem: the problem is that gcc tries to create a folder in `/var/cache/ccache/tmp` (notice that this is not under htdocs, but it is an absolute path) - which it is not allowed to. I think this is reasonable. Generally, a PHP program should not be able to touch anything of that sort...

Comment: so what do u suggest...

Comment: i created a var/cache/ccache/temp and put 777 (just for now) ...still not working

Comment: i did yum remove cache ....it remvoed the permission denied error....but no output still

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yum remove cache did the trick